# Restaurant tables Laravel multiple table merge

Tags: laravel, merge

I have not done this project but am going to start helping out starting soon,

The Development team is having a problem that they can not get a solution to.

when merging 2 tables (ex. table 1 and table 2) it works fine and table 2 is connected to table 1. but merging more then 2 tables there is the problem.

ex. table 1, table 2, table 3

both table 2 and table 3 show connection to table one but instead it should be table 2 is connected to table 1 and table 3 is connected to table 2. all the tables should be connected in a row.

They are using laravel.

Hope someone can give a helping hand as I am not sure what to do and would like to give a solution to this problem

Best regards

Comment: Could you try and be more specific (table structures, relationships etc), it would make it a lot easier to help you out.

Comment: post your model and controller code for relationship